# Convert images for Cardboard display on Android

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I want to convert one (or two) images (transform in perspective, offset, size, etc), so I can display it with 3D effect on Cardboard. The images are taken by ordinary webcams. I use two `ImageView`s + `Bitmap` now.

In a word, I want to transform a common image into *photosphere* effect. Anyone could give me some suggestions on how to do correct transformations/manipulations on the image data to realize this?

Comment: Why don't you use the Cardboard API provided by Google!

Comment: @PrerakSola I didn't know where to start. Having a glance at Cardboard API, it provides unity related examples. I want to deal with actual photos. Anyway, I will look for possible tutorials with extra time. Thanks for your information.

Comment: There is really little literature on how to use the API. The contained example is about rendering with GL.